# how to build pkg for mac console app with mkbundle --static flag

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio, mkbundle

I have written a console Mac utility using Xamarin Studio.
I then created a bundle using:

- mkbundle myapp.exe *.dll -o myapp --deps
- pkgbuild --analyze --root Release name.plist
- pkgbuild --root Release --component-list name.plist --sign "john doe" --install_location /Applications/myapp myapp.pkg

When installing myapp.pkg on another machine and attempting to run the app,  there was a runtime error "libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib' referenced from myapp - image not found'.

That would indicate that the machine did not have the mono runtime installed.   And that is correct, it does not have the mono runtime installed.

I tried to run mkbundle with the '--static' option.  However, then the pkgbuild --analyze returns an empty component list.

My question is how to build a deployment pkg when using mkbundle with the --static flag?  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done.  The Mono framework is too large and the toolset do not allow this functionality.  You can not create a package with pkgbuild without a dependency list.

I solved the problem by telling the user to download the monolithic Mono framework.  He was not happy with the 500MB download but the app worked.